# Tess4j and NetBeans Java Programm - Problems "AWT-Eventqueue-0" unsatisfied-link-error

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, tess4j

I have programmed a small tool that takes an image and uses tesseract to extract data from it. I have used Java in Netbeans on a 64bit Windows 7 machine. So far, the programm compiles perfectly fine and does what I want - including tesseract -. But when I try to clean & build the finished project in Netbeans and try to run the generated .jar in the .cmd

```
java -jar "..\Users\Marv\Scantool.jar"
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The module can not be found

                at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
                at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
                at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
                at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
                at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
                at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
                at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
                at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:45)
                at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:283)
                at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:219)
                at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:168)
                at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:152)
                at ScanCards.ScanCards.extraction(ScanCards.java:64)
                at ScanCards.ScanCards.scan(ScanCards.java:37)
                at ScanCards.ScanCardsGUI.scanButtonActionPerformed(ScanCardsGUI.java:16
        0)
                at ScanCards.ScanCardsGUI.access$100(ScanCardsGUI.java:22)
                at ScanCards.ScanCardsGUI$2.actionPerformed(ScanCardsGUI.java:73)
                at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:20
        22)
                at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.jav
        a:2348)
                at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel
        .java:402)
                at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259
        )
                at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonL
        istener.java:252)
                at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
                at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
                at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
                at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888
        )
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)

                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
                at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
        rivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
                at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
        rivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
        rivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
        ad.java:201)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
        java:116)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
        ad.java:105)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

So far I can narrow the problem down to this line in my code:

```
String strResult = instance.doOCR( file);
```

I have checked the "file" given to the OCR. It is a perfectly in tact .tif-image (as it works inside the Netbeans fine anyways). Another thing I thought that could be the problem that the .jar can't find the for tesseract necessary .dlls. So have copied the necessary .dlls into the "dist"-folder. With no success either. 
I have inbound the tess4j-1.3.0.jar into my project's library.

It is quite strange that everything runs perfectly fine inside of NetBeans. I think I miss a link to a library but I can't think of any.

That is all I can think of to provide you with. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found some kind of a workaround...

```
File dummy = new File( ScanCards.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getParentFile().getParentFile();
String dirStr = dummy.getPath();
instance.setDatapath( dirStr);
String result = instance.doOCR( file);
```

Actually I am still unable to run the .jar-file but I am able to run it from the console. So instead of the runnable .jar I am just using a batch-file ( including the 'java -jar PATH\TO\MY\FILE' code) to start the programm.

I think, that the key lies in the "java -jar", it seems as if by opening the .jar directly java is not loaded?